# Running offlineimap via launchd doesn't survive sleep on OSX

Tags: launchd, offlineimap

I'm not very well versed in all things `launchd` but I wrote this `plist` file that periodically runs `offlineimap` to fetch new mail from IMAP servers:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
<dict>
    <key>Label</key>
      <string>net.dpo.offlineimap</string>
    <key>ProgramArguments</key>
      <array>
          <string>/usr/local/bin/offlineimap</string>
          <string>-o</string>
      </array>
    <key>RunAtLoad</key>
      <true/>
    <key>KeepAlive</key>
      <true/>
    <key>ProcessType</key>
      <string>Background</string>
    <key>StartInterval</key>
      <integer>1800</integer>
</dict>
</plist>
```

The file is located in `~/Library/LaunchAgents/net.dpo.offlineimap.plist`.

The issue is that the process doesn't seem to wake up when I wake the computer from sleep. Running

```
$ launchctl stop net.dpo.offlineimap
$ launchctl start net.dpo.offlineimap
```

reactivates it, but that seems to defeat the `KeepAlive` option.

I tried using

```
<key>KeepAlive</key>
  <dict>
    <key>SuccessfulExit</key>
      <true/>
    <key>NetworkState</key>
      <true/>
  </dict>
```

but I observe the same behavior. I'm on OSX 10.9. My `~/.offlineimaprc` doesn't use the `autorefresh` option.

Is anything wrong with the `plist` file?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

Well, I may be misunderstanding the meaning of `KeepAlive`. It turns out [Homebrew](https://brew.sh) distributed a `plist` file with `offlineimap` that does the job:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple Computer//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
  <dict>
    <key>KeepAlive</key>
    <false/>
    <key>Label</key>
    <string>homebrew.mxcl.offline-imap</string>
    <key>ProgramArguments</key>
    <array>
      <string>/usr/local/opt/offline-imap/bin/offlineimap</string>
    </array>
    <key>StartInterval</key>
    <integer>300</integer>
    <key>RunAtLoad</key>
    <true />
    <key>StandardErrorPath</key>
    <string>/dev/null</string>
    <key>StandardOutPath</key>
    <string>/dev/null</string>
  </dict>
</plist>
```

The daemon now survives sleep.